# How can I check if a value is in my array?

Tags: php, arrays

This is my array `$data`:

```
array(3) {
   [0]=>
      string(4) "icon"
   [1]=>
      string(6) " image"
   [2]=>
      string(12) " description"
}
```

I try to find out if a value is existing in my array:

```
if (in_array("description", $data))
{
    echo "Match found";
}
else
{
    echo "Match not found";
}
```

But my result is `Match not found`

I am at a loss.

Comment: Downvoted because it shows very little effort in self-solving and is largely unhelpful to future readers.  Please consider deleting this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line `$data= array_map('trim', $data);`  before your if statement. So the final code will be

```
$data = array('icon',' image',' description');
$data= array_map('trim', $data);
if (in_array("description", $data)){
    echo "Match found";
}
else{
    echo "Match not found";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Php function `array_search()` is for exactly what you need.

Here is the example

```
if( array_search('description', $array) ){
   echo 'Exist';
}else{
   echo 'Not exists'
}
```

To know More about array_search(), please use this link
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
if (in_array(" description", $data))
    {
    echo "Match found";
   }
   else
    {
    echo "Match not found";
   }
```

OR

```
$data= array_map('trim', $data);

if (in_array("description", $data))
        {
        echo "Match found";
       }
       else
        {
        echo "Match not found";
       }
```

Either will work, and check you have space infront of description element.

Give it a try, this will work.

Comment: Thanks mate ! If your problem has been solved in either solutions I had gave, you can accept my answer !

Answer (score 1):

**string(12) " description"** here have a space but **(in_array("description", $data))** don't have any space . So, how could be you wish to _____ ?

At first you have to **trim** you all of description using trim function

```
$data=array_map("trim",$data);
```

Then use **in_array** to get expect result ..

Answer (score 0):

See your array $data has values like `description` and `image` which contains one extra space.

When you creating array use `trim` function to avoid white spaces and your code will work.

```
if (in_array(" description", $data)) {
    echo "Match found";
   } else {
    echo "Match not found";
   }
```